# how to use external font in expandable listview?? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, listview, fonts, expandable

hi i'm trying to change the font of the parent text (the subjects) in my expandable list view by using an external font. i've already placed my font in assets>fonts. context is red in my code here

subjects_adapter.java

```
    public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
    String group_title = (String) getGroup(parent);
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parentView, false);
    }
    TextView parent_text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_text);
    Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "PLAYBILL.ttf");
    parent_text_view.setTypeface(regular, Typeface.NORMAL);
    parent_text_view.setText(group_title);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? can you give me an example code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use custom font in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio)

Comment: i tried this and placed the code after onCreate in MainActivity.java but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),
            "fontname.ttf");
    parent_text_view.setTypeface(regular, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Place in your groupview after initialization of parent_text_view

Hope it works fine

Comment: font extention that is by default wat is ur font name

Comment: playbill.tff i edited my question by the way, i tried the code but it's with an error

Comment: have u replaced parent_text_view.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); with    parent_text_view.setTypeface(regular, Typeface.NORMAL);

Comment: yes i have, but context in Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "PLAYBILL.ttf"); then shows in red

Comment: name should be in small letters not the capital it will throw error edit file name in assert folder as playbill.ttf and in the code too

Comment: i changed it to small letters but the word context is still in red

Comment: whr is it showing in parameter or the whole line 
I worked on the same it is not showing any error

Comment: the parameter only. it says cannot find symbol variable context. here's a screenshot: http://puu.sh/lCBaN/b6b5540e0b.png

Comment: where do i place ctx.getAssets()? i don't have it yet

Comment: in place of context.getAssets()

Comment: Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "playbill.ttf");