# How to apply custome fonts in android studio once for whole Project

Tags: android

I need to apply custom fonts in my android project once for whole project. helps will be appreciated.

Comment: create a theme and put your font code in that

Comment: first you can extend the Application class, createFontFromAsset() and use reflection to asign it to all components or you can use this thrid party library https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy, its a shame android doesnt allow a decent way to apply custom fonts for app except for system ones

Comment: By using [Android-DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html), it will be easy for you to set more than one custom fonts, check reference link on [androidgig.com](http://www.androidgig.com/setting-custom-font-through-xml-with-databinding/).

Comment: Responses appreciated. Was helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is the answer which was posted by me on this Link.  [How to use custom font in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio/38939405)
Here we have a better way to apply fonts on EditTexts and TextViews on android at once and apply it in whole project.

First of All you need to make fonts folder. Here are Steps.

1: Go to the (project folder) Then app>src>main

2: Create folders named 'assets/fonts' into the main folder.

3: Put your fonts into the fonts folder. Here I Have 'MavenPro-Regular.ttf'

Here are the Steps for applying custom fonts on EditText and using this approach you can apply fonts on every input.

1 : Create a Class MyEditText (your preferred name ...)

2 : which extends EditText

3 : Apply your font

Here is code Example;

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

And in Here is the code how to use it.

```
MyEditText editText = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

editText.setText("Hello");
```

Or in Your xml File

```
<MyEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    />
```