# How to do "article like" layout?

Tags: android-layout

I'm newbie, I don't know what is this called, So i cant google it.

[image]

I want to make an "article like layout"  on my scroll view.
How can i put like this on my scroll view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are asking is a card view to use the library you have to paste this code in your gradle

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
```

}

and place the content like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="Hello Card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here is a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)
and to make it look exacty like the image try to use custom font
you can set i like this

```
`   TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf");

tx.setTypeface(custom_font);`
```

fore more about [custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio) hope this will help you.