# Adding font in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

like the title says, I need to use a new font. I currently use Android Studio 2.3.3.

I have a file **.ttf (a font file)** and I would like to add this font in the res directory (/res/font).

I saw other questions, but it seems that things are different because a lot of people use Android Studio 3.0.

So, for us poor people, which is the right process?

Comment: you can try this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27588966/7413139)

Comment: "i would like to add this font in the res directory (/res/font)" -- that is not supported by Android Studio 2.3.3 and its related tools. There are [many libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/37?sort=created) to assist in adding fonts to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.create a new `fonts` directory in the `assets` directory and put the `your.ttf` font file here.**

**2.You can change to this .**

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/your.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

**Edit**

**You also can use `android:typeface="sans"` 、`android:typeface="serif"` 、`android:typeface="monospace"`  in your xml code .**

**Use `android:fontFamily` in the xml code**

From android 4.1 / 4.2 / 5.0, the following [Roboto](https://material.google.com/resources/roboto-noto-fonts.html) font families are available:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"     // roboto black
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

**Also use in the style**

fonts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="font_family_light">sans-serif-light</string>
    <string name="font_family_medium">sans-serif-medium</string>
    <string name="font_family_regular">sans-serif</string>
    <string name="font_family_condensed">sans-serif-condensed</string>
    <string name="font_family_black">sans-serif-black</string>
    <string name="font_family_thin">sans-serif-thin</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: There is no way to change font directly in xml files? Or set it in a style resource file?

Answer (score 1):

you can use CustomTextView

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}
public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
        String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_font);
        try {
            if (fontName != null) {
                Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
                setTypeface(myTypeface);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

}

You need to create a attrs in values folder

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
    <attr name="font" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

after for textview in xml

```
<com.packagename.view.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:textColor="#313131"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:font="@string/monte_semibold"
    />
```

the font name you mention in xml should be available in assets/fonts/ folder

Comment: I liked this solution since it allows to "pass the font name as a parameter", sort of speak. Thanks