# Activity Instance does not exist- null object reference

Tags: java, android, class, textview, typeface

I am trying to develop an Android application. For my use case I want to use a custom typeface and I wrote a that gathers all available `TextViews` in a View, so that I can set the typeface easily by a loop. I thought I should source out the text manipulation things to an own class named `TextManager.class` . But now when I am executing the app I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

It occurs when I am trying to set Typeface in TextMangaer.class . I did a bit of research and found out that it is because the activity instance does not exist at this point. But I don't get it why, cause when I am trying to do this in Start.class there is no problem.

```
//Start.class
public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // set fullscreen

    //Initialize shared preferences
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("User", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=prefs.edit();

    setContentView(R.layout.start_screen);
    TextManager textManager= new TextManager();

    textManager.setTypeface(getTextViews((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_menu)));

}
}
```

and my **TextManager.class:**

```
public class TextManager extends Start{

public TextManager(){
super();
}

public void setTypeface(List<Integer> idsOfTextViews){
    Typeface typeFaceIkarosLight= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/ikaros_light.otf");
    for(int i=0; i < idsOfTextViews.size();i++){
        ((TextView)findViewById(idsOfTextViews.get(i))).setTypeface(typeFaceIkarosLight);
    }

}
}
```

So how could I fix this or how should I write this? If anybody could help me figure it out that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: font/ikaros_light.otf files are in asset folder?

Comment: in New Oreo version you can set the custom font in XML.

Comment: where are you calling super() to inherit parent classes context?

Comment: @Paul_hundal I just added it in the constructor, but still the same issue.

Comment: where you put font file ? location

Comment: follow this it will helps you -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio

Comment: If `TextManager` is not being used as an `Activity`, it should not extend an `Activity`. That's why the `Context` is null. Remove `extends Start`, and pass a `Context` to `TextManager`, either in a constructor, or a method.

Comment: @MikeM this helped me out

Answer (score 1):

Problem is context is null for getting assets.

Use `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` in case of being used in an activity but if it is being used in a fragment then use `getActivity().getContext()`

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),  "font/ikaros_light.otf");
```

Instead of

```
Typeface typeFaceIkarosLight= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/ikaros_light.otf");
```

Comment: Either wit getContext() nor with getApplicationContext() it does not work. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to make method which return typeface instead passing textview ids as an argument. you can do it like this :

```
public Typeface getTypeFace(Context context){
    Typeface typeFaceIkarosLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/ikaros_light.otf");
    return typeFaceIkarosLight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom fonts then you can take this example

This tutorial will show you how to set custom font on `TextView`, `EditText` and on `Button`.

http://androiderstack.com/index.php/2017/08/14/use-custom-font-in-textview-edittext-and-button-in-android/

This will surely help you