# How to use Custom font in android using gradle library?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i want to a use **custom** `font` in my application

i refer this link : [How to use custom font in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio)

this work for me but i want to change a font using : `gradle` library

so can anyone have solution.

Thanks Advance

Comment: So basically you want to use different fonts for different gradle build flavours?

Comment: i want change font using library

Comment: try this library https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: okey let me try this and thank you @NirmalPrajapat

Comment: you want to change font for complete application?

Comment: nope i want to change a font of `TextView` etc. @AbdulKawee

Comment: textview etc? all where text is displayed?

Comment: in my recyclerView

Comment: only i want to know which library is used other step i know @AbdulKawee

Comment: Thank you So much its work for me @NirmalPrajapat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!!!

```
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
}
```

For detail go through [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-library-recommendations) and [this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Comment: Thank you so much @Arnold Brown

Answer (score 1):

Check official [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html).

1. Put your fonts in font resource folder
2. Create font-family
3. Use your font for your TextView for example

Comment: dear but my question is using gradle library so i need library. becoz using library code is reduce so

Comment: Your choice, but this is official android way