# How I use Urdu in my android project.

Tags: android-studio-3.0, urdu

[want to make an android application on **Islam**.... just want to add Urdu in my project as in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhtU.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your  "YourProjectFolder/app/src/main/res" folder, then
2. Create a folder named "values-ur" folder in res folder
3. Create file "strings.xml" inside values-ur
4. Inside that strings.xml add your strings,eg:

"urdu_text" is your urdu strings.

In your Activity class take  getString(R.string.text_one),
and if you have a textview, textview.setText(getString(R.string.text_one));

For more info : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I am very beginner. I don't know what are you saying... Can you please explain it....?

Comment: Not able to save these strings in **strings.xml** file

Comment: What is the error. check syntax for declaring a string is correct or not

Comment: When I am going to save this string. **<resources>
<string name="test">میں ایک پاکستانی ہوں</string>
</resources>** But receiving this error C:\Users\Shakeel Mughal\AndroidStudioProjects\AssanIslam\app\src\main\res\values-ur\strings.xml
This file contains character in Unicode format which will be lost if you save this file as an ANSI encoded text file. To keep the Unicode information, click Cancel below and then select one of the Unicode options from the Encoding drop down list. Continue?

Comment: check any of your strings have special characters like "&" or something..and also your folder name should be values-ur inside res folder..

Comment: I did it. Thanks **Sir** dev

Comment: Happy to help..Pls upvote

Comment: Sir dev.... How I add urdu fonts in my project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio This link will help

Answer (score 1):

You just required to have all text in urdu unicode.
Android Activity, layouts supports urdu. sqlite3 also supports urdu.

Comment: I am very **beginner**. I don't know what are you saying... Can you please  explain it....?