# How to use 'apple system font' in android application

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, font-family

We developed an application in IOS using 'apple-system-font' and we loved this font so we want to use the same font for all TextViews in the android application.
So Is there any way to use 'apple-system-font' in the android application like the following:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:fontFamily="-apple-system-font" />
```

Comment: You need to get the Font Resource,which would have an extension as .ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest iOS uses 'Helvetica Neue' as system font. You need to download the font file and then add it in your assets. This process is explained in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Note that Apple may choose to change this font over time. Also, even though the font is highly legible and crisp, the users on an Android device may not be used to seeing it. this may result in a 'different' experience for them. Make sure you do proper user testing before adding the feature in production app.