# How to use the "others versions" of a Font?

Tags: java, fonts, awt

The font Calibre have Light, Light Italic, Italic, Regular, Bold and Bold Italic versions.

Using the example: `Font font = new Font("Calibre", type, 48);`

To use Calibri Italic I have to use `type = Font.ITALIC`

To use Calibri Bold I have to use `type = Font.BOLD`

To use Calibri Regular I have to use `type = Font.TRUETYPE_FONT`

But how can I use Light, Light Italic and Bold Italic versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could I suppose just use the Calibri Light font:

```
Font font = new Font("Calibre Light", Font.ITALIC, 48);
```

Or you can load the font, the following will load the **Calibri Light Italic**:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream(
            new File("calibrili.ttf"))).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 48);
```

The above code line will of course need to be wrapped within a **try/catch** block since the exceptions **FileNotFoundException**, **FontFormatException**, and **IOException** could possibly be thrown.

[**Calibri**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/calibri) is a Microsoft Font and it packages 6 font files which are:

```
calibri.ttf       The Standard Calibri font
calibrib.ttf      Calibri Bold
calibrii.ttf      Calibri Italic
calibril.ttf      Calibri Light
calibrili.ttf     Calibri Light Italic
calibriz.ttf      Calibri Bold Italic
```

You will note that using a font type of ***Font.ITALIC*** actually does nothing since **Calibri Light Italic** is an Italic font. However ***Font.BOLD*** will bold the italic text

Answer (score 0):

It is the custom font in android studio.Here is the similar question. It should work for you[code for custom font in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio)