# "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped" when I Press A Button

Tags: java, android, crash

I made a quiz game with codes I found on github because I'm a newbie and I want to learn programming.
So, when I press the start button game crashes. I tried it without the other classes but it still crashes. There is my MainActivity class, MainActivity xml and AndroidManifest.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton baslat,ayarlar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    baslat = findViewById(R.id.baslatButonu);
    ayarlar = findViewById(R.id.ayarlarButonu);
    baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoruAlani.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }

    });
    ayarlar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ayarlar.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/deepPurple"
tools:context="com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logoIsim"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="@string/logoIsim"
    android:textColor="@color/orenji"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="150dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logoIsim"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/play_button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/basla"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/baslat"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/baslatButonu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ayarlar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/ayarlar"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ayarla"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings_button"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sosyalMedya"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ayarlarButonu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/sosyalMedya"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/facebookLogo"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/sosyalMedya"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook_logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sosyalMedya"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/sosyalMedya"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"


    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/twitterLogo"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sosyalMedya"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitter_logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/slackLogo"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/slack_logo"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sosyalMedya"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sosyalMedya"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sosyalMedya"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


<activity android:name=".TekrarOyna" />
<activity android:name=".OyunKazanma" />
<activity android:name=".SoruAlani" />
<activity android:name=".SureBitti">

</activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

**logcat**

```
 05-25 12:28:18.414 6393-6393/com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi 
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi, PID: 6393

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

                   ComponentInfo{com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi/com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi.SoruAlani}:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Bariol_Regular.otf

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)

    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)



    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found 
    fonts/Bariol_Regular.otf

    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:190)

   at com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi.SoruAlani.onCreate(SoruAlani.java:51)

   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)

   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)

   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)

   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 

   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 

   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 

   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 

   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 

   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 



  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 

   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
   05-25 12:28:20.016 4207-6527/com.android.providers.calendar E/SQLiteLog: 
   (284) automatic index on view_events(_id)
   05-25 12:28:26.129 1535-1602/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 
   '2cf4e81e 
 com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi/com.proje.bilgiyarismasi.bilgiyarismasi.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: add just the exception part of the logcat

Comment: Try removing **+** sign from `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/baslatButonu"` in playButton

Comment: learn debugging, there are lots of videos on youtube. Learn to post crash logcat for bugs you can't debug.

Comment: read this for +id and id https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025971/8089770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not casted the image buttons correctly.

Use this in `onCreate()`

```
    baslat = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.baslatButonu);
    ayarlar =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ayarlarButonu);
```

And Declare this activity in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Ayarlar">
```

From the logcat

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Bariol_Regular.otf**
```

Add this font file also 
**Bariol_Regular.otf**

Check this link please
[How to use custom font in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio)

Comment: In new android studio casting is not necessary .  and i think activity name is MAinActivity isn't it?

Comment: yes you are right , cant say  @Kangaetemo is using In 3.0 with sdk 26 :)

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that i'm using 2.3.3. And thanks for answer but game still crashes and I can't see anything new on logcat

Comment: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity** 

     Declare this activity in manifest please , if u have not added it yet

Comment: and **java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Bariol_Regular.otf**

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: let me know if it helps or not

Comment: @quicklearner I deleted everything related to fonts and game started to work! Maybe it was giving error because of the fonts extension? There is a problem with the header text but I hope I can handle that. Thank you

Comment: I am glad it worked ,happy coding ,u can refer the link how to use a font in studio and please upvote my answer if it helped so others can refer it