# Adding your own fonts to an android project

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to add two fonts to my project: OpenSans-Semibold and OpenSans-Regular. But the names of these fonts contains capital letters which aren't supported at AS. I tried to rename one of this font and I didn't manage to do it. On the other hand I didn't rename these fonts and include them at me design but AS said that all font names can't have capital letters. And right now I don't know what to do because I would like to use these fonts from xml, not changing programmatically like this way:

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf");
tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-a-project-written-in-android-studio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font) questions, but I didn't find a solution of my problem. I tried to add my font files to special folders and then use them, but it didn't work anyway. Hope that my problem has the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976600/7666442

Comment: hello. please make sure that you have put your font(.ttf file) inside fonts folder under the assets folder.

Comment: @NileshRathod, I saw this answer, but I have added my font which contains uppercase letters, and AS show me error

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko then rename your font file in lowercase

Comment: @NileshRathod, thank you for your help :)