# Some of fonts from pc not visible in android studio editor's setting

Tags: android-studio, fonts

My operating system is windows. So in my PC there is one font called 'Ayuthaya.ttf' (*that's not windows default font*).

[image]

I want to use this font in android studio. But in font list from android studio settings I can't find that font.

[image]

But in IntelliJ's settings the font is visible. So how can I fix it?

Comment: This type of question has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-a-project-written-in-android-studio

Comment: That's another question. Please read again))

Comment: Please top re-adding noise to your questions. Who decides to downvote or vote to close as a duplicate is entirely out of your control - such notices are also actively removed, [along with thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/6296561). I've also rolled back several of your rollbacks, as they actively degraded the quality of your questions. Also, please re-read [ask]

Comment: Some kind peoples will understand you and will not give downvote, so that is necessary in some point))

Answer (score 5):

This might be a little too late but in case someone encounters a similar problem.

If you are running **Windows Build 1809** then a **possible solution** would be:

1. **Delete** your currently installed font.
2. **Select** the font or fonts (regular, light, etc...).
3. **Right-click** & select "**Install for all users**".
4. **Restart** Android Studio.

This happens because since build 1809 fonts are installed to:

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts

while before build 1809 they were installed to:

> C:\Windows\Fonts

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I've actually had this issue in the past, this kind of issue usually happens when you change the default font on Windows. For example, I changed my default windows font to "San Francisco" by Apple and it literally made everything on Android Studio unreadable.

To fix the issue, just change the default font on Windows. If you're having trouble changing the font then I can provide you with a script to change the font.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some questions. How can I know what's my windows default font right now and what font to set as default font?

Comment: The font on Windows 10 is called Segoe UI, its default for all windows 10 users.