# Android: setTextTypeFace font asset not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Trying to set the font programmatically.

My file is located in src/main/res/fonts/material_font.ttf

```
circleProgress.setTextTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "material_font.ttf" ))
```

and i've tried

```
circleProgress.setTextTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/material_font.ttf" ))
circleProgress.setTextTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "font/material_font.ttf" ))
circleProgress.setTextTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(applicationContext.assets, "fonts/material_font.ttf" ))
...
```

The error is:

```
Font asset not found MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
```

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use `createFromAsset()`, your font would need to be in `src/main/assets/`.

Comment: Just as @CommonsWare mentioned, you need to copy your font file to assets directory instead. If the folder does not already exists create it. You can take a look at this answer to a similar question too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27588966/3475551

Answer (score 1):

we look at the source code and document, for `Type.createFromAsset`

```
     /**
     * Create a new typeface from the specified font data.
     *
     * @param mgr  The application's asset manager
     * @param path The file name of the font data in the assets directory
     * @return The new typeface.
     */
public static Typeface createFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path)
```

so you should put the `font.ttf`in the asset file path

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing this if you do not wish to save your font file to assets directory

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.material_font.ttf);
circleProgress.setTextTypeface(typeface)
```