# Change default android font location

Tags: android, fonts, location

I want to use some custom fonts in xml but I don't want it to be read from res/font. Is there anyway we can change the location from where the fonts are read ?

Comment: you can keep them in assets. if using Kotlin use extension functions otherwise custom Text view class. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-a-project-written-in-android-studio

Comment: Where do you want to read it from ?