# how to prevent fontFamily from changing when system-font is changed in compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing android with compose now.
The Text widget is set by FontFamily.Default.
My Galaxy 20 has several font families(Default, SamsungOne, Thick Gothic), and when I change them, the compose text FontFamily is also changed.
I want to prevent this from changing.
Is there any way about this?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Set a font family using the `fontFamily` parameter.

```
Text(
    text = "I'm Roboto Font",
    fontSize = 22.sp,
    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.roboto_medium, weight = FontWeight.Medium)),
    color = Color.DarkGray
)
```

You can downlod the fonts from the [Google Fonts site](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto). Put them in the `res` > `font` folder. [Follow this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-a-project-written-in-android-studio).

Comment: If I set the FontFamily in each Text, they are not effected by system font? As watching your answer, it looks like an answer for setting custom fonts. But what I want to is setting absolute font family

Comment: I tested the code in my samsung mobile. Even if I change the font in the system settings, it is not affecting the app. What do you mean by absolute font family?

Comment: Ok I will try it. What I mean for absolute font family is font family that is not affected by system font setting. And Is there any way to not using FontFamily(Font())?